# Django: Upgrading sqlite3 database on MacOS, Python still showing the older version even after upgrading

Tags: python, django, sqlite, anaconda

I had sqlite3 version `3.23.1` installed. and the sqlite binary file path is:

```
/anaconda3/bin/sqlite3
```

then I downloaded the sqlite3 zip file from https://sqlite.org/download.html (version 3.35.4).
Then followed the following commands to upgrade my sqlite3 database:

```
which sqlite3

sudo mv /anaconda3/bin/sqlite3 /anaconda3/bin/sqlite3-old

sudo chmod -x /anaconda3/bin/sqlite3-old

mv /downloads/sqlite3-downloaded-directory/sqlite3 /anaconda3/bin/

sudo chmod +x /anaconda3/bin/sqlite3
```

Then I checked the version:

```
sqlite3 --version
```

and it showed the upgraded version

```
3.35.4
```

But then I went into my Atom editor where I am writing my Django application and entered into the python shell using:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and then checked the version from here using the following commands:

```
>> import sqlite3
>> print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
```

but it is still showing the older version i.e `3.23.1`

Does anyone has an idea how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some future readers:

As I am using Anaconda package manager to I used the following way to upgrade the sqlite3 database in python:

```
conda install -c anaconda sqlite
```

And then in the python shell check the sqlite version:

```
>> import sqlite3
>> print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
```